# Yii2 headers sent twice when running console from web app

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yii2

Hi I'm trying to deploy a Yii2 app to Google App Engine Standard (Not Flex).

Standard environment doesn't allow background tasks or `popen()` or even writing to `php://stdout`. Also GAE Cron as Queued tasks seems to use **http** to communicate with other services. So I'm trying to figure out a way to wrap my console apps by a web service to which I'll restrict access to intern use only. My attempt is the following action:

```php
public function actionMigrateTest()
{
    /**
     * GAE use
     * https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/
     */
    // defined('STDOUT') or define('STDOUT', fopen('gs://stdout0/stdout', 'w'));
    // defined('STDERR') or define('STDERR', fopen('gs://stdout0/stderr', 'w'));

    /**
     * local use
     */
    defined('STDIN') or define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
    defined('STDOUT') or define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
    defined('STDERR') or define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));

    $migration = new \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController('migrate', Yii::$app);
    $status = $migration->runAction('up', ['migrationPath' => '@app/migrations/', 'interactive' => false]);

    fclose(\STDOUT);
    fclose(\STDERR);
}
```

That works fine and the script is executed after uncommenting the top lines to write to GAE storage instead of `php://stdout`. And there is no problems when the response I find written into that file is something similar to this:

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.15.1)

No new migrations found. Your system is up-to-date.
```

The problem is when the console task is executed and the response is something like:

```
...
...
*** applying m180206_052910_create_variant_value_table
*** applied m180206_052910_create_variant_value_table (time: 0.129s)


15 migrations were applied.

Migrated up successfully.
```

Just after that successful script the following error is raised (in GAE as in my local environment):

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Migration.php on line 591.' in /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send()
#2 /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Migration.php on line 591.' in /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Response->send()
#2 /Users/salem/Sites/kt/shell55/web/index.php(28): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

Any idea on why headers are being sent twice with that specific response or how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrap migration run with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` or put `exit` at the end of this method to prevent further processing.

```
public function actionMigrateTest()
{
    ob_start();

    defined('STDIN') or define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
    defined('STDOUT') or define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
    defined('STDERR') or define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));

    $migration = new \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController('migrate', Yii::$app);
    $status = $migration->runAction('up', ['migrationPath' => '@app/migrations/', 'interactive' => false]);

    fclose(\STDOUT);
    fclose(\STDERR);

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Since 2.0.14 Yii does not allow to echo in the controller, you need to return response. There are several similar issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/search?q=HeadersAlreadySentException&type=Issues).

Comment: Just a little note to add to anyone trying to achieve the same: `$status` [should be equal to **0**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-console-controller#runAction()-detail) if no errors are thrown in the console app. So you may need to manually throw an exception if it has a different value in case you don't want to return a `200` status code when console fails.